# Does a ThinkPad x230 i7 support a 4k external monitor?

Tags: thinkpad, external-display

I'm looking to buy an external monitor for my ThinkPad x230 with an i7 CPU. Is it possible to use a 4K display like this [Dell UltraSharp](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-ultrasharp-27-4k-monitor-u2718q/apd/210-amlm/monitors-monitor-accessories) with it?

[Here are the full ThinkPad x230 Specs](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-thinkpad-x230-2325-12-5-core-i7-3520m-windows-7-pro-64-bit-8-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd-series/specs/) + I'm running it with 16GB RAM and the latest Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ThinkPad has an Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU.  It supports resolution up to 1920×1200 through HDMI and 2560×1600 through DisplayPort.

The Dell monitor you listed has a 3840x2160 resolution.

While the ThinkPad will work on that monitor, you would be paying for a monitor that exceeds the laptop's graphics capabilities.  You could buy a cheaper monitor, or purchase it if you plan on upgrading your laptop in the future.

Comment: Thank you, what kind of GPU is needed to run the full 4k resolution?

Comment: @Tom https://www.lifewire.com/4k-resolution-overview-and-perspective-1846842

Comment: For those who are interested. 4k is supported but only at 30hz - Source: https://www.thinkscopes.com/2014/08/10/thinkpad-compatibility-with-4k-lcd-thinkvision-pro2840m/

Comment: i5-3320m in another x230 *does* support 4K @ 30Hz over Display Port

Answer (score 1):

Your Notebook has the [Core i7-3520M](https://ark.intel.com/products/64893/Intel-Core-i7-3520M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) CPU that comes with [Intel HD Graphics](https://technewswith.me/intel-hd-graphics-guide) 4000. Unfortunately, it only supports a maximum resolution of 2560×1600. 
You should instead get the BenQ GL2706PQ Monitor which has a display resolution of 2560 X 1440. It is a 27” Inch Monitor with a response time of just 1ms.

Or you can simply get a cheap monitor having 1920x1080p resolution. The HP Pavilion 27XW would be a good choice.